# Сохранение страницы\файла WEB+JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, веб-программирование, файлы

Всем доброго времени суток!

Идея такая(предложите другую, если чувствуете, что я ушел в дебри):

1) Пользователь в форме пишет комментарий

2) Я с помощью JS + document.createElement(..) создаю блок с его комментарием

3) /* тут начинаются проблемы */

Когда я создаю элемент, то его видит только тот человек, который его написал и только в рамках текущей сессии (пока страница не будет перезагружена).

3.2) Я хотел брать содержимое этого блока и записывать его в файл, чтобы потом при загрузке страницы прочитать его и заполнить блок содержимым файла, но уперся в проблему того, что я не могу создать файл на сервере. (возможно могу, при помощи fs из Node.js - если да, то напишите краткий код, пожалуйста)

4) **ВОПРОС:** Как мне можно сохранить для всех пользователей изменения?

Comment: Сохраняйте в базу, в чем проблема? Только подумайте о фильтрации ввода сначала...

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов , используя PHP + MySQL?

Comment: Да хоть Python + Oracle.

Comment: По логике, комменты должны хранится в бд. В ответ на запрос к серверному приложению, оно должно рендерить страницу из jade-темплейта, в блоке комментариев через цикл сформировав верстку из комментариев из базы данных. Это серверный, самый простой вариант. Если у вас вся логика вынесена на фронтенд, то можно сделать что-то типа REST API, и из фронтенда отправлять AJAX- запрос  GET   по адресу  /comments , а серваком на такого вида запрос отправлять  комментарии из базы данных в JSON:
[{"username":"user1","comment":"blablabla"},{"username":"user2","comment":"author is faggot!"}] в таком виде.